# How to only allow particular programs to modify certain files?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, file-permissions, windows-8.1, restrictions

I want to make certain directories on my drives read-only *except to particular programs* who will have full permissions.

For example, the Microsoft Word might be allowed to modify the files in my Documents folder, but other programs (such as the Command Prompt) would not be allowed to.

I'm guessing this requires a file system filter driver of some sort, but I don't know which programs have this capability.

Is there any (free) program that can do this for me?

Comment: This wouldnt be possible natively...  I havent heard of anything that does this.

Comment: Program based.. I don't see how this is possible. USER based, then yes possible. You can limit directories only accessible to certain users. You can even remove Administrator access to certain directory, and change ownership to the point the folder is close to useless unless to that specific user. But of course if the user is able to access "Run as Administrator" then nothing is safe.

Comment: @Keltari: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. It's basically the same thing that an antivirus does -- it denies access to some programs except itself.

Comment: as I said, natively windows cant do this.

Comment: @Keltari: I didn't ask how to do it natively either, I asked if there's a program that can do this.